# Filezilla: Ask for a directory at login

Tags: ftp, filezilla

At work we have a large website - I "own" three directories. I am wondering if I can have only two sites in the site manager in Filezilla, but after supplying a password, it asks which remote directory I wish to go to, versus having to navigate down from the root, or have 6 identical sites (dev and live) in the manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In trying, and failing, to find a way to cause such a prompt I kept overlooking that you already have this available.

Just create your two sites, and then after connecting enter the desired directory into the "Remote site:" field that appears above the directory tree/file listing. It's functionally identical to the prompt you're after, but just happens to be built directly into the interface(currently reads `/16x16`):

[image: Filezilla main window screenshot]

Is that somehow not enough?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Thanks for the image edit. I was running out the door (also: lazy) when posting that.

Comment: I know about that text field. For personal reasons I cannot use the mouse...

Answer (score 1):

Create a `symlink` like

```
ln -s /path/to/real/directory /where/to/make/link
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that using the FileZilla Site Manager I like to set "Default remote directory" under the advanced settings. You can add all the different permutations of directories on the server as separate sites.

[image: FileZilla Site Manager Default remote directory]

Your six sites need not be identical in the manager. You could do:

- example.com - DEV
- example.com - LIVE
- example.net - DEV
- example.net - LIVE
- example.org - DEV
- example.org - LIVE

But all of them could have the same hostname/username/password combination, but by using the "Default remote directory" to put yourself in the correct virtual host directory you *don't* have identical sites in the site manager.

Comment: This would be the "six identical sites" situation from the question that he doesn't want.

Comment: @Su' that's not how I read the question. They actually say "or have 6 identical sites (dev and live) in the manager" like that might be another alternative. They're saying it's the drilldown that's no good. I've updated my answer. If I've misunderstood the OP won't choose my answer. No harm no foul.

Comment: @artlung Su is correct with their comment.